# How to alter JavaScript code temporarily and browser-ishly on an existing page

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the weirdification of the wording in question. Feel free to improve but, please, **read and understand** the intention of the question first.   :)

Sometimes, when I code, a bug may happen to magically appear in my code (without me being involved, of course - it's like the immaculate conception so to speak). In most cases, one just corrects the error in the code and uploads the source. Poof, problem's gone!

But sometimes, the evil computer will persist at developing new unwanted behavior based on the new code and in some rare occasion (i.e. pretty much always), I end up in trial and horror, uploading a gazillion times over.

It occurs to me that it'd be nice to be able to try out different inputs on client-side. At the moment I achieve that by making the regarded functions and variables global, as follows. This way I can access those from the console.

```
globoTheHolder = {};
globoTheHolder.doing = function(input) { ... }
globoTheHolder.knowing = "knowing nothing";
```

However, I'd like to know if (and in such case how) I can access a function declared the usual way, i.e. in the *SCRIPT* tag or linked to the rendered HTML file from a JS file.

Comment: Downvoter - care to comment so I can edit and improve the question? I left my mind-reading ability in the other pants.

Comment: You could attach it to `document` or `window`.

Comment: @putvande That's what I do, although nicely packaged in *globoTheHolder* as not to throw garbage all over the memory. I'm looking for a way to **access** the stuff from the client **without** making it global (i.e. without placing it in *document* nor *window*). Not sure if there's a way to do that but I'd like to know.

Comment: How are you doing it now? If you declare a function in the global scope you should be able to access it.

Comment: @putvande I'm doing it by **not** putting the keyword *var* when I initialize *globoTheHolder*. It's put automatically into window, then.

Comment: "uploading a gazillion times over" sounds like a workflow problem. Don't you have a local copy of the site that you can work on and then deploy when it's ready?

Comment: @DaggNabbit When I do have a local copy, the work is much easier. But now I'm doing an Azure-project with limited access to stuff. The document fetches some data and other goodies but only when requested from **that** page. I know, I could do the mockup of the inputs but I'll be doing a bunch of different small projects so it'll be time well-wasted. Bottom line, I need to upload for **every** change as the page is tangled into other less-than-optimal approaches.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I don't know the Azure terminology for this stuff but if I were in a situation like that I would probably just ssh in and use vim rather than uploading stuff over and over, is something like that not an option?

Comment: @DaggNabbit Azure = no access to the server locally, e.g. only uploads allowed and using strictly the publish-file distributed by the client. Short answer - nope. :(   I really do need a way to access **and alter** JS on the client without reloading (since that would re-load in the original version). By your question I'm starting to suspect that it's a no-go.   :(

Comment: @KonradViltersten, you can alter scripts, in Chrome at least, from the Resources panel of the console. But it does sound to me like there is a serious workflow problem here that should probably be resolved.

Comment: @DaggNabbit Yes, definitely. But it's faster to find a work-around than to persuade this particular client. Especially now, over the holidays - nobody's there, hahaha (or rather hohoho). I'll try out Chrome (usually I Fox my way through the code). If you compare to what one can do with CSS - I can turn on/off styles, enter my own parameters and watch how screwed up the site gets. Something like that but for script would be awesome. Now I'll be off to Chromifize my development.   :) Compile the comments into a reply so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "try out different inputs on client-side" I assume you mean something like:

```
   var v1 = {
       buggy_function: function ()
       // ...
       };

   var v2 = {
       buggy_function: function ()
       // ...
   };
```

so that you could upload your code only once and then try `v1.buggy_function()` or `v2.buggy_function()` as you see fit. Is that so?

Well frankly I don't think you will find a tool to automate this.

You can copy-paste bits of code into the console to redefine variables or even functions on the fly, but that's about it, and it seems a terribly awkward way of doing things to me.

I don't understand your need for sparing you "gazillions" of uploads to begin with.

Don't you have a local apache serving a dev version of your site on localhost? Or is it the fear of getting blisters from the F5 key?

Installing Apache on your computer seems the pretty obvious solution to me: hello Mr localhost, bye bye Mr globoTheHolder.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Some of the functionality I'm using is fetched from a secure location and provided to me by the server my script runs on. I have no means/mandate to call these from my local environment, sadly. I've been provided with an API that is, let's say, less then well-documented, so I end up trying out different inputs and such. Not an optimal way but that's what the client's provided. The way I see, I'll have to keep on going like I did before or code some mocked-up layer pretending to be the right data. The latter creates a whole bunch other issues, though. Thanks, anyway. Short answer is: "CAN NOT".

Comment: Ah well, you can trust those pesky clients to find ways to throw us poor programmers back to the stone age. Good luck, then :)